# Setting openGL ES 1.1 as default in xcode 4 for iOS5

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have the latest Xcode. When I setup a new project to use OpenGL ES it seems that Xcode creates it using OpenGL ES 2.0.

How do I make Xcode open projects using OpenGL ES 1.1 instead?

Answer (score 8):

Xcode doesn't really "open projects using OpenGL ES 1.1." The IDE has some stock templates that you can choose for starting new projects, with one of them being an OpenGL ES application. These templates are updated with almost every version of Xcode released, so what they provide as a starting point changes over time.

Currently, the "OpenGL ES Game" template in Xcode 4.2 uses GLKit and assumes OpenGL ES 2.0 capabilities are present on the target device. Given that all devices that run iOS 5.0 (which is needed to use GLKit) support OpenGL ES 2.0, this is a safe bet for a template like this. With developers like Marco Arment [reporting that fewer than 3% of iOS devices out there don't support OpenGL ES 2.0](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper) you can see why Apple may have decided to focus on that for their template.

This, however, doesn't mean that you can't develop applications which only target OpenGL ES 1.1 using the latest versions of Xcode. You're just going to need to write your own code to set up the 1.1 context, or start from another template out there. For example, [this simple cube sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip) I wrote for my class has renderers for both OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0. You can just use the 1.1 path as the basis for your application.

I do recommend taking a look at supporting OpenGL ES 2.0, given that almost all iOS hardware out there supports it now and because it gives you some very powerful capabilities.

Comment: Can you give a detailed instructions on how to set it up? Bec. xcode 4.2 use the lastest SDKs and if I use the opengl template it uses the 2.0 version not the 1.1

Comment: @user1576519 - As I said in the answer above, what the templates provide changes with each Xcode version, and the latest templates are 2.0-only. You can use the sample application I link to above as a starting point for a 1.1 / 2.0 application. One word of caution, though: Xcode 4.5 no longer supports ARMv6 devices, so you can't build applications using that which target the older hardware that didn't support OpenGL ES 2.0. You'll need to use Xcode 4.4 to target that older hardware.